# Object disappearing when rendering in cycles / rendered preview

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, mesh, texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

So I tried flipping normals and made sure there is no z clipping going on. But this object just doesn't render for some reason.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello maybe you've enabled the Holdout option in the Object panel > Visibility? If it's not your problem, please share your file (at least some of its objects)